# How do I disable mining in `bcoin`?

Tags: miner-configuration, bcoin

When running `bcoin`, how does one disable mining by default? I just want to run a full node without mining. There seems to be no config options to control it.

Comment: Why do you assume `bcoin` is mining by default? I'd be extremely surprised if it was capable of mining by itself at all.

Comment: Mining is disabled by default, it must be switched on with rpc commands and like @PieterWuille said it can only usefully generate blocks for test networks.

Comment: @pinhead: I think that's an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mining is disabled by default, it must be switched on with RPC commands:

https://bcoin.io/api-docs/#rpc-calls-mining

Keep in mind without additional hardware, bcoin can only effectively generate blocks on test networks (like simnet and regtest). A bcoin full node can be used by a mining pool operator to generate block templates and ultimately find valid blocks, there has been [at least one block](https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/issues/160) mined on mainnet with a bcoin full node.